# Failed to boot live usb except Ubuntu 14.04 on my Fujisu P771

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, kubuntu, live-usb

I really need help and I am not an expert in computer and I am stuck.

I have an old `Fujitsu P771 (2012) i7-2617M @1.5 GHz, 4 GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 3000` running dual boot on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 that I want to replace with Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.

This laptop was previously manifested with adware and I have succeeded to remove them though it may have some errors left that I cannot or know how to fix them all completely. The only error shown is just the `Windows Script Host Access is Disabled ....` that pops up when the Windows start.

I have tried to fix it via the registry and did not work so I leave it this way because other things still working. Also, the screen's backlight is dead. This means whenever I am still in the bootloader, the screen will just go dark and I will depend to the flashlight to see. It is difficult to capture what is going on before I am able to boot into one of the OS selection since then I can use an external monitor.

Now here is the problem with Ubuntu installation.
**It seems the laptop cannot read any bootable USB drive aside from Ubuntu 14.04. So far I have tried Linux Mint, Ubuntu Studio, Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 18.04, and Kubuntu 20.04. All of them failed to boot on my Fujitsu except Ubuntu 14.04. I also have tried using different USB drives, none of them worked except when I put Ubuntu 14.04 on them.**

Whenever I tried to boot the USB drive via the default BIOS, it only loads some command line and says "Invalid...." (was difficult to read due to the dead backlight) and then quickly it goes blank.

Meanwhile, I have checked the bootable USB drive on my other laptops and everything was running fine. It can boot and install, different USB drives, different Linux distros. So it is not the USB drives, it is my Fujitsu that somehow would not read.

I tried to look for BIOS Update, but I could not find any version specifically for my laptop from the official Fujitsu website (or it might be already the last update). So I searched for an alternative until I found this `PLOP boot manager` that I think can bypass the BIOS problem. I installed it and able to open PLOP during the Windows boot (after GRUB2). But then the Kubuntu bootable drive cannot be read too by the `PLOP boot`. My Fujitsu's BIOS is Phoenix Technologies Ver. 1.13, 3/8/2012.

I don't know what is going on here, and I don't have the ability to solve this problem myself! I would prefer installing the newest `Kubuntu 20.04` because of its `LTS` and the interface which I love so much. If not, any Ubuntu distros that is still in service would be fine.

Comment: Wat is the CPU in that laptop? And what happens when you can't boot an Ubuntu LiveUSB?

Comment: It's i7-2617M CPU @1.5 GHz, 4 GB RAM, and Intel HD Graphics 3000

Comment: Plenty of annoying PUP adware that keeps installing. Formatted D: partition. I am afraid to format the C: because I still want to keep the Windows. Additionally, whenever I tried to make a backup from my Windows it seems the malware had blocked some of the Windows security systems including the backup (I hadn't solved it).